# Fat burning supplements and their efficacy

Tags: supplements, fat-loss

I understand that the general consensus is that one should rather rely on exercise/training and proper nutrition to lose fat.

However, I'm wondering what else can be used to accelerate this process. I've heard that ECA stacks are sort of risky (and ephedrine is illegal in the US now). What do people use to accelerate such processes these days?

I did a little bit of research on google scholar, and the only supplement which seems to have some scientific papers on it are [green tea extracts](http://www.ajcn.org/content/70/6/1040.short), but I've only done a little amount of search.

Are there any other supplements which can help the fat loss process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Four Hour Body](http://fourhourbody.com/) suggests a stack called PAGG:

- Policosanol (20-25mg) - seems to enhance the fat-burning effect of the rest of the stack
- ALA (100-300mg) - increases glucose uptake into muscle, leaving less to be deposited as fat; inhibits triglyceride production
- Green Tea Extract (325mg EGCG) - inhibits glucose storage as bodyfat; increases programmed cell death in mature fat cells
- Garlic Extract (200mg) - allicin component inhibits fat regain

Take "AGG" before each meal and "PAG" (no Green Tea) before bed. Extra vigilance in consuming adequate B-complex vitamins is recommended with this stack.